# SSL certificate error on ip but nothing on domain name

Tags: ssl, apache2

I'm hosting an apache service and trying to install SSL certificates for the first time.

I obtained a domain on godaddy, lets use example.com. I edited my dns settings so that when I go to example.com it redirects to my server. This is all working fine.

However when I go to `https://example.com`, my connection times out. If i however go to `https://xx.xx.xx.xx` , I get connected, but google chrome throws an error that its probably a stolen certificate since I'm not accessing it via the domain.

Does anybody have any tips on how to fix this? I want to be able to connect to `https://example.com` and arrive at my server.

I'm running apache2 on a ubuntu 16.04 desktop edition that I use as server.

Comment: Can you give us the domain? This sounds like you didn't point `example.com` at the right IP.

Comment: sure, the domain is novinav.com

Comment: It looks like you've set up GoDaddy's domain masking instead of an A record. That's not likely to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have used GoDaddy's "domain forwarding" instead of a real A record.

GoDaddy's domain forwarding servers don't have your certificate installed, nor do they respond to HTTPS, so they're not responding to the requests. Their domain forwarding solution is just an iframe hosted on their servers.

You'll want to turn off the forwarding, and set up an A record to your IP address, `94.226.25.87`.

Comment: After a whole day of cursing and searching you saved the day. thanks!

Comment: @KennethBreugelmans Glad I could help. GoDaddy really glosses over the huge downsides of this "feature" of theirs.